# character counter in Python 3 without built in functions

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, file-management

So I have to create a program that reads a paragraph from Romeo & Juliet and returns the number of characters, number of spaces, number of words, and the top 3 most common characters without the use of built in functions such as counter. I made this program to use parallel lists to count unique characters and add a tally into the second list. My problem lies in being able to pick out the top three and print the two lists (i.e. "A 3").

This is the txt file the program reads:
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

This is the program I have so far:

```
charCount = []
uniqueChar = []

char_count = 0
word_Count = 0
space_count = 0

Open_File = open("romeo.txt")

for romeo in Open_File:
    for char in romeo:
        if (char == ' ' or char == '.'):
            word_Count += 1
        if (char == ' '):
            space_count += 1
        if (char != ' ' and char != '\n'):
            char_count += 1
            if (char not in uniqueChar):
                uniqueChar.append(char)
                charCount.append(1)
            else:
                for j in range(len(uniqueChar)):
                    if (uniqueChar[j] == char):
                        charCount[j] += 1

print("Spaces: ", space_count)
print("Char: ", char_count)
print("Words: ", word_Count)
```

Comment: [These](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) are built in functions. - `counter` aint one.

Comment: He mentioned counter by name. He wants us to specifically use parallel lists.